Npm link does not link types
I have this line in my package.json:
"types": "./dist/main.d.ts",

So, using npm link I expect it to link my .d.ts file with this package too.
VS Code can see my type definitions and doesn't show any errors, but after I try tsc or ts-node it gives me an error 2307 (Cannot find module or its corresponding type declarations)
You can repeat this issue by cloning this (note: it is not default branch; use git checkout no-types-example after cloning) and running npm link, then npm run example
If I use npm pack and install tgz, types are working properly
If it does not suppose to give me types here, then how do I link with types locally?
npm -v: 10.9.0

I guess, the solution is using smth like npm i --link /path/to/module, and it works, but only from external directory. If I try to run it still being in folder that contains my repo I gave link to above, it still has the same error when i am trying to run an example script

I'm a bit confused, why would npm run example will run something? you dont have a file call example nor script

You just need to add "name": "somename" to your package.json, and of course, have a script that run those files. Your reproduce repo is lack of some way to run “example”.

Or dist/main.js, tried both, both working fine.
Add to tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
        // works also with ES2022 and NodeNext
        // with ES* no need to specify the whole path
        "module": "ESNext",
        "noEmit": true
    }
}

Edit for follow up:
The key that is important to understand is that in order to have a package, you need package.json. 
If package.json is in the root of the dir tree, and no other dir has package.json of his own, they are all part of the same package unless you manually exclude them.
If you want to mimic usage of your package by script/package you should do it from outside the package, meaning separate directory, or having another package.json in the directory using your package from inside the package tree.
npm link let you link one package to another "like" you installed one in the other. 
For example, in your case, you create two separate folders, each with its own package.json and run npm link in notypesexample then you go to example folder and run npm link notypesexample. 
The result will be two:

example has notypesexample as a dependency, and its looks a bit better than import base on location.
a change in notypesexample is immediately reflected in example so it's easier to keep working.

But — it is for development only, in prod you use packed modules and you import them as modules (or packages).
As for myself, never used npm link, and never had the need to, sharing example for testing packages from other "semi" packages, so you can see how i do it (doesnt mean its better).
ValKey-Glide node - In this package we write in TS, and our users want it to be compatible both with ES and CJS. 
So I worked on a way to provide the package for both and wanted to add testing for it that will behave as someone using the package from outside.
hybrid-node-tests Check the code here, it's look like I'm importing the package, but if you'll go to package.json you'll see that it is a workaround, but It's behave the same and I get my goals.
Hope it helped a bit.

I gave a link to specific branch, here it is, once again: https://github.com/Vishota/vi-package-template/tree/no-types-example

It has name. And what I need is to import this package by name in typescript, like here https://github.com/Vishota/vi-package-template/blob/no-types-example/example/main.ts

Actually, as I wrote in answer, i could do it using smth like import pkg from '../', just path to the package folder. But it still is not clear why doesn't it work with types after npm link

And it is types only issue. When in my other project I use tsc and then run js by node ("example": "tsc ./example/main.ts & echo ===EXAMPLE=== & node ./example/main.js") it gives me an error, but writes compiled .js file like tsc usually does. And after compiled .js file launched by node it works properly.
That all is not really a problem for me now, but I just would like to understand how npm link works here

Im editing my answer

Thanks. But I think "noEmit" is not too compatible with webpack (which I use in this example). It gives me Error: TypeScript emitted no output. More details https://gist.github.com/Vishota/07f268c98bdfec296030d0d356212e43

You absolutely right, i forgot about it, i don't use webpack. But there is something fitting for webpack, ill find it when in front of a computer.

But - as long as you don't have separate package.json file for example or its not a successor, npm will see it as the same module and the best you'll get is from "..", you can't import a module from the same module.

Just to make sure i understand your goal - you just want the type recognition to work? No matter how the import statement looks like? What else do you need from the structure? Im very fine with eslint/ts/node but bundler are less my thing so i need to understand the specifics.

Actually what I wanted at the beginning was just making example script, which imports the package that I develop. I have tried npm link and it didn't work as I expected, so I got a little confused, but then (after creating a question) I've realised that there also is just import from '../' approach, so basically problem was solved there. There is only a small theoretical ambiguity left regarding why npm link did not work, but practically I can just do without it

I wouldn't say I'm too bad at all these npm stuff, but at that moment I didn't think about import from '..' somewhy (maybe cos I haven't sleep for about 35 hours, idk). Thank you very much for help!

That still would be cool if you could explain how npm link worked here. As I know, it just creates symlink in global modules folder, so it should work similar to how it works with importing using relative path

ill edit my answer so i can explain

Thanks, that helped

So if you need to have your package somewhere on your device, you can use npm i --link /path/to/your/package and then import it using package name
For some reason this will not work if you are located in the same repo with its package.json file. In this case we just have to import your package from relative path like import package from '../'
